# Constraint solver that can handle floating point exponentiation

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc, coin-or-cbc, gecode, highs

Are there any constraint solvers that can understand exponentiation of potentially unbounded floats aka. real numbers?

Given this simple program,

```
var float: x;
constraint x^x = 27;
solve satisfy;
```

I have tried [Gecode](https://github.com/Gecode/gecode), [HiGHS](https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS), [COIN-BC](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc), and [Chuffed](https://github.com/chuffed/chuffed).

*Chuffed* just doesn't support floats:

```
Type var float is currently not supported by Chuffed.
```

The others don't understand the power operator:

```
Error: solver backend cannot handle constraint: float_pow
```

Ideally I am looking for a solver with a Zinc frontend, although this is not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JaCoP solver generates the following solution.

```
%% WARNING: constraint float_pow is not defined for negative numbers as first argument (decomposition x^y = exp(y*ln(x))); x::{-1.0E150..1.0E150} has minimal value negative (will be pruned).
x = 3.0;
----------
==========
```